# Find all the combinations for each element in mutliple arrays

Tags: javascript

I have  the following object

```
var mapping = {
    0: ['A','B','C'],
    1: ['D','E','F'],
    2: ['G', 'H', 'I'],
    ---
    ---

    9: ['X','Z']
}
```

There is a function that references the above object and finds all the possible combinations. For example, we have

```
function combination(value){}
combination([1,0]); // DA, DB, DC, EA, EB, EC, FA, FB, FC
```

So in the above invocation the keys at "1" and "0" from the map object will be referenced and all the possible combinations for those two will be returned.

I think the best way to solve this would be to use a recursion, but i just can't seem to wrap my head around this

Comment: Is `mapping` really an object of number indexed properties? Does it contain a `length` attribute denoting the number of entries? Are entry keys contiguous (1,2,3,4... not 1,5,9,10,22,...)?  Can it be an array?

Comment: @Raj Powar: Expanding your question in a generic way, it should be the combination of n items taken at a time, where n is the length of the input mapping key array. You seem to be expecting always a combination of 2 all the time no matter the length of the mapping key array. Please add new information about your question in the question itself, not elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Not just recursion you can use multiple for loops to achieve this

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < mapping[index1].length ; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0 ; j < mapping[index2].length ; j++)
    {
        resultArray.push(mapping[i][j]);
    }
}
```

here resultArray is the output array, index1, index2 are the indexes passed

Comment: yes true my very first thought, but what about case when it looks like this combination([1,0,9,8])

Comment: Raj Powar, please specify how the result should look like for such an input.

Comment: so lets take combination([1,0,9]) this would print out DA, DB, DC, EA, EB, EC, FA, FB, FC, XA, XB, XC, ZA, ZB, ZC, XD, XE, XF, ZD, ZE, ZF

Answer (score 1):

Close enough:

```js
var mapping = {
    0: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    1: ['D', 'E', 'F'],
    2: ['G', 'H', 'I'],
    9: ['X', 'Z']
}

function combine(array, index1, index2) {
    var result = array[index1].map(function (el1) {
        return array[index2].map(function (el2) {
            return [el1, el2].join('');
        })
    });
    return [].concat.apply([], result);
}

function combineAll(array, indices) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < indices.length - 1; i++) {
        var index = indices[i];
        var nextIndex = indices[i + 1];
        result = result.concat(combine(array, index, nextIndex));
    }
    return result;
}

var combinations = combineAll(mapping, [1, 0, 9]);
console.log(combinations);
document.write(JSON.stringify(combinations, null, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks @ShanShan i added a minor tweak to your solution as it was missing out one of the combinations, so i added another for loop

Answer (score 0):

To find all possible combination we have to iterate over mapping object as well  as array corresponding to given key, here i create two functions `combination` which will iterate over mapping object keys and `map` which will iterate of array corresponding to each given key:

```
var mapping = {
0: ['A','B','C'],
1: ['D','E','F'],
2: ['G', 'H', 'I'],
3: ['J', 'K', 'L'],
4: ['M', 'N', 'O']
}

var resultArray = [];

function combination(x){
 for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    for(var j=i+1;j<x.length;j++){
        map(x[i],x[j])
    }
  }
 }
function map(index1,index2){


for (var i in mapping[index1])
{
    if(mapping[index1].hasOwnProperty(i)){
        for (var j in mapping[index2])
        {
            if(mapping[index2].hasOwnProperty(j)){
                resultArray.push(mapping[index1][i]+''+mapping[index2][j]);    
            }

        }        
    }

  }    
}


combination([0,2,1,4])
console.log(resultArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion in order to solve this problem.
Simply iterate through the indices, and try to add every corresponding item recursively.

I have implemented a working JS function for you:

```
function combination(o) { // just a wrapper for convenient usage
  var current = [];

  function step() { // recursive function
    if (current.length === o.indices.length) { // combination is ready
      o.callback(current); // callback
      return; // and leave recursion
    }

    // current.length is a current position (0, 1, 2, 3 etc.) for which we find a value
    // o.indices[o.current.length] is an index of mapping for current position (0, 2, 2, 1 in a demo below)
    // o.mapping[o.indices[o.current.length]] is simply a row 

    o.mapping[o.indices[current.length]].forEach(function(x) {
      current.push(x);
      step();
      current.pop();
    });
  }

  step(); // start recursion
}
```

You can use it this way:

```
combination({
  mapping: { // your mapping
    0: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    1: ['D', 'E', 'F'],
    2: ['G', 'H', 'I']
  },
  indices: [0, 2, 2, 1], // indices may repeat
  callback: function(x) { // callback will be called every time we find a combination 
    document.body.innerHTML += x + "<br/>"; // x is an array
  }
});
```

Here is the [working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tp8yazmw/).

Answer (score 0):

Following is a solution using recursion.

It does a `DFS (Depth First Traversal )` to find all the paths of length corresponding to the input array.

For every dive to the next level, the array gets shortened using `slice(1)`. The original array is not modified and the pattern repeats. When there are no more elements in the array, the path is printed.

I have added a count to see how many combinations are generated. The count should be a product of the lengths of all arrays in the initial input array.
That is for snippet with input array `[2,0,3,7]` , the product is `3 * 3 * 4 * 3 = 108`, i.e 108 combinations.

Essentially picture a tree with the first level nodes with all `mapping[2]` elements, each of those have `mapping[0]` children making level 2 of the tree, each level 2 then has `mapping[3]` elements as children at level 3 and finally `mapping[7]` would make up the leaf nodes of the tree. This can go to any level based on your input array and your mapping configuration.

The code below does a recursive traversal of the above tree, each time going from root to each leaf node and prints out that path.

```js
var mapping = {
    0: ['0A','0B','0C'],
    1: ['1A','1B','1C'],
    2: ['2A','2B','2C'],
    3: ['3A','3B','3C', '3D'],
    4: ['4A','4B','4C'],
    5: ['5A','5B','5C'],
    6: ['6A','6B','6C'],
    7: ['7A','7B','7C']
     
}

var count = 0;

function traverse(arr, comb) {
     if(!arr.length) {
        console.log(++count + " : " + comb+"\n"); 
        return; 
      } 
      for(var j =0; j < mapping[arr[0]].length; j++) 
         traverse(arr.slice(1), comb + " " +  mapping[arr[0]][j]);
}

traverse([2,0,3,7],"");
```